# Data generation plan failed because of duplicate PRIMARY KEY constraints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, primary-key, database-project, data-generation

In VS2010 database project, I try to generate test data for a table that has existing data (by clicking 'No' when prompted). Identity column (that is the primary key) is SQL computed value so I can not change the data generator for that column.

So why the data generation plan doesn't recognize existing primary key values in the database, but tries always to insert duplicates, i.e., seems that the plan is starting always from the seed value, not from the next available identity column value? Can I force the data generation plan to start from some other seed value for this particular table?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my second question: seems that from the schema view, I can set some other seed to start from. Still, I don't understand why the data generation plan doesn't automatically recogzine the next available IDENTITY value.